# Walk and shoot not work in diagonal

Tags: java

Hy, i have a problem to manage imput game

i would implement all 8 movement + shoot in 8 direction, now i can move in 8 direction , shoot but stationary in 8 direction , and move and shoot in north,south,east,west,and north-east.

i have 5 volatile boolean (the problem not change without volatile)

```
private volatile boolean north;
private volatile boolean east;
private volatile boolean south;
private volatile boolean west;
private volatile boolean shoot;
```

that set true when arrow key is pressed with key binding and set false otherwise

```
    private void setKeyBindings() {

    InputMap inMap = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap actMap = getActionMap();


         inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "UP" + "pressed");
         inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "UP" + "released");

        actMap.put( "UP" + "pressed", new AbstractAction() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //directionMap.put(direction, true);
            north=true;
        }

    });
    actMap.put("UP" + "released", new AbstractAction() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //directionMap.put(direction, false);
            north=false;
        }
    });


     inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "DOWN" + "pressed");
     inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "DOWN" + "released");

    actMap.put( "DOWN" + "pressed", new AbstractAction() {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //directionMap.put(direction, true);
    south=true;
   }

});
actMap.put("DOWN" + "released", new AbstractAction() {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //directionMap.put(direction, false);
    south=false;
   }
});

inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "LEFT" + "pressed");
inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "LEFT" + "released");

actMap.put( "LEFT" + "pressed", new AbstractAction() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   //directionMap.put(direction, true);
    west=true;
}

});
actMap.put("LEFT" + "released", new AbstractAction() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   //directionMap.put(direction, false);
    west=false;
}
});

inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "RIGHT" + "pressed");
inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "RIGHT" + "released");

actMap.put( "RIGHT" + "pressed", new AbstractAction() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 //directionMap.put(direction, true);
    east=true;
}

});
actMap.put("RIGHT" + "released", new AbstractAction() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 //directionMap.put(direction, false);
    east=false;
}
});



inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false), "SPACE" + "pressed");
inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true), "SPACE" + "released");

actMap.put( "SPACE" + "pressed", new AbstractAction() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 //directionMap.put(direction, true);
    shoot=true;
}

});
actMap.put("SPACE" + "released", new AbstractAction() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 //directionMap.put(direction, false);
    shoot=false;
}
});




inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, 0, false), "SUCCESSIVA" + "pressed");

actMap.put( "SUCCESSIVA" + "pressed", new AbstractAction() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 //directionMap.put(direction, true);
    mondo.player.selectArmaSuccessiva();
}

});



inMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, 0, false), "PRECEDENTE" + "pressed");

actMap.put( "PRECEDENTE" + "pressed", new AbstractAction() {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//directionMap.put(direction, true);
        mondo.player.selectArmaPrecedente();
}

});

}
```

---

in the thread to control the booleans variable to realize also diagonal movement

```
            if(shoot){
            System.out.println("SHOOT");
            if(mondo.player.selectArm!=-1)
            mondo.proiettili.add(mondo.player.spara());
        }
        if(north && west && !south && !east){
            System.out.println("NORD OVEST");
            mondo.player.direction=(PuntiCardinali.NORTH_WEST);

        }
        if(north && east && !south && !west){
            System.out.println("NORD EST");
            mondo.player.direction=(PuntiCardinali.NORTH_EAST);


        }

        if(south && east && !north && !west){
            System.out.println("SUD EST");
            mondo.player.direction=(PuntiCardinali.SOUTH_EAST);

        }
        if(south && west && !north && !east){
            System.out.println("SUD OVEST");
            mondo.player.direction=(PuntiCardinali.SOUTH_WEST);

        }
        if(north && !west && !east && !south){
            System.out.println("NORD");
            mondo.player.direction=(PuntiCardinali.NORTH);

        }
        if(south && !west && !east && !north){
            System.out.println("SUD ");
            mondo.player.direction=(PuntiCardinali.SOUTH);

        }
        if(east && !north && !south && !west){
            System.out.println("EST");
            mondo.player.direction=(PuntiCardinali.EAST);

            }
        if(west && !north && !south && !east){
            System.out.println("OVEST");
            mondo.player.direction=(PuntiCardinali.WEST);
        }
        if(!north && !south && !east && !west)
            mondo.player.direction=(PuntiCardinali.STOP);
```

When i move only it work good,
 but when i shoot it work only for north,south,est,west and only north-east.
why only north-east?
if i stop direction with player oriented in any diagonal and shoot it shoot,
 It is as if when i move diagonal shoot became false

Comment: Do you need to set the player direction before you shoot? Like, add the shoot commands after all instances of `mondo.player.direction`?

Comment: Where does it shoot when you are moving, per say, southwest?

Comment: I'm more asking: How does your player shoot? Is it just the direction he is facing? If not, can you make it like that?

Comment: player have direction and orientation so if direction is stop orientatio have one of 8 cardinal point, if direction is cardinal point orientation is ugual at it

Comment: i think that i have an error in input because print ("SHOOT" ) isn't whene i press space + arrow up + arrow left
thanks for reply

Comment: player shoot creating a new bullet give its orientation that became direction for the new bullet

Comment: Note that common PC keyboards are just not designed to support arbitrary amount of simultaneous keypresses except for the modifier keys (Ctrl, Shift, Alt). That is why games use these keys for shooting, crawling, running, zooming and the like. See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses for some keyboard models supporting what you want (though the referred post is 5 years old)

Comment: i prove to change in VK_CONTROL for shoot action but i have another problem , the player don't stop to walk

Comment: Resolved thanks, i changed the arrow key with WASD and SPACE for shoot, it work fine.
Thanks a lot